# AWS cloudformation: is supporting multiple LogDrivers possible in ContainerDefinitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, grafana-loki

I have a task in my CloudFormation template which originally used `FluentD` as `LogDriver` (to push logs to our `ElasterSearch` server), recently we wanted to push the logs to `Loki` as well, so we need to change the `LogDriver` to `json-file` instead.

```
  GreenTaskDefinition:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition'
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: green-container
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: json-file
            Options:
              max-size: 100m
              tag: green
            # LogDriver: fluentd
            # Options:
            #   fluentd-address: localhost:24224
            #   tag: docker.container.green
            #   mode: non-blocking
            #   fluentd-retry-wait: 30s
            #   fluentd-async-connect: true
```

I would like to ask if it is possible to have multiple LogDrivers supported in a container, so that we can have logs in both ElasticSearch and Loki?

Answer (score 1):

No, only one `LogConfiguration` is supported per container. You would have to implement forward operation to `Loki` yourself.

Comment: Any hints/references on how to implement the forward operation to Loki?